# Cassandra bechmarking using YCSB

Tags: cassandra, benchmarking, ycsb

Can YCSB 0.1.4 be used to evaluate performance Cassandra 1.1.6?

Comment: This question gets us into the weeds very quickly.  While the tool may work well (I'm not familiar with it) the Cassandra link on their site does point to a very old (and missing) Cassandra site. Then there's the question of the usefulness of such a low-level performance test (I'd rather you performance test the data persistence tier on top of the data base or even the business logic tier above that.  I'd say this regardless of which data base vendor you wanted to performance test.

Answer (score 2):

At HP we've tried out Cassandra 1.1.6 with YCSB 0.1.4 on HP ProLiant Gen8s. I can't share the results, but the question was merely "does it work" and to that the answer is "sure". But we didn't use the YCSB-Cassandra driver. We changed the YCSB-JDBC driver -- it's possible nowadays because CQL exists. We had to change a few lines in YCSB's JdbcDBClient.java source because CQL requires a column list for INSERT, and because we had to ignore INSERT's error returns.